# How to loop through a list of BQ tables in Python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I've a list of BQ tables that I'd like to use one at a time. The purpose is to process each table individually, perform some action (in my example, score the dataset for a previously fitted model), then compute, append, and save the probabilities in the `all scores` list.

Here's a screenshot of the entire code snippet.

```
# List of BQ Table
scoring_tables = ["`Customer_Analytics.HS_AF_PROPERTY_ALL_DATA_SCORE_PV_CLEANED_01`",
"`Customer_Analytics.HS_AF_PROPERTY_ALL_DATA_SCORE_PV_CLEANED_02`",
"`Customer_Analytics.HS_AF_PROPERTY_ALL_DATA_SCORE_PV_CLEANED_03`",
"`Customer_Analytics.HS_AF_PROPERTY_ALL_DATA_SCORE_PV_CLEANED_04`",
"`Customer_Analytics.HS_AF_PROPERTY_ALL_DATA_SCORE_PV_CLEANED_05`"]


# List to store probabilities/scores
all_scores = []

# Loop through each BQ tables, calculate, append and store the probabilities in the all_score = []
for t in scoring_tables:
    %%bigquery property_data_score_00
    SELECT * FROM t 
    score_data = property_data_score_00.copy()
    
    
    score_data.set_index('HH_ID',inplace = True)

    # Fixing for HOUSE_INCOME = 0 & AGE = 0 based on means
    score_data['HOUSE_INCOME'] = np.where(score_data['HOUSE_INCOME']==0,107,score_data['HOUSE_INCOME'])
    score_data['AGE'] = np.where(score_data['AGE']==0,54,score_data['AGE'])

    # recategorize PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE | PROP_GRG_TYPE | PROP_ROOF_TYPE
    condition = [(score_data['PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE'].str.contains("BRICK")),
    (score_data['PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE'].str.contains("WOOD")),
    (score_data['PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE'].str.contains("CONCRETE")),
    (score_data['PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE'].str.contains("METAL")),
    (score_data['PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE'].str.contains("STEEL"))]
    choice = ["BRICK","WOOD","CONCRETE","METAL","METAL"]
    score_data['PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE_MOD'] = np.select(condition,choice,default="OTHERS")

    condition = [(score_data['PROP_GRG_TYPE'].str.contains("ATTACHED")),
    (score_data['PROP_GRG_TYPE'].str.contains("DETACHED")),
    (score_data['PROP_GRG_TYPE'].str.contains("CARPORT")),
    (score_data['PROP_GRG_TYPE'].str.contains("BASEMENT"))]
    choice = ["ATTACHED","DETACHED","CARPORT","BASEMENT"]
    score_data['PROP_GRG_TYPE_MOD'] = np.select(condition,choice,default="OTHERS")

    condition = [(score_data['PROP_ROOF_TYPE'].str.contains("GABLE")),
    (score_data['PROP_ROOF_TYPE'].str.contains("HIP")),
    (score_data['PROP_ROOF_TYPE'].str.contains("GAMBREL"))]
    choice = ["GABLE","HIP","GAMBREL"]
    score_data['PROP_ROOF_TYPE_MOD'] = np.select(condition,choice,default="OTHERS")

    # one-hot encoding
    to_encode = ["IND_ETHNICITY","IND_GENDER","IND_MOVERS_FLAG","IND_OCCUPATION","IND_REGION","PROP_EXTR_WALL_TYPE","PROP_GRG_TYPE","PROP_ROOF_TYPE","TSI"]
    score_data_dm = pd.get_dummies(data = score_data, columns = to_encode, drop_first = False)

    columns_not_in_score_data_dm = [c for c in train_X.columns if c not in score_data_dm.columns] #columns which might not get produced during pd.get_dummies(data = score_data....), if categories are not available in score data

    score_data_dm[columns_not_in_score_data] = 0 #initializing above columns as 0

    score_data_dm_filt = score_data_dm[select_columns] # making sure to select only the columns which are in the train_X

    y_pred = xgb_prop_PV.predict_proba(score_data_dm_filt)[:,1] #final scoring
    
    all_scores = all_scores + y_pred
```

Inside the looping, I'm having trouble with the `SELECT * FROM t` step. The error is shown below. I believe the indent within the loop is causing the `%% bigquery` step to fail. I looked at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) here, however it appears that it is only useful when conditional looping is there, which is not the case in my situation.

Also, this appears to be a complex approach; is there a more elegant solution? Because the table was too large (600GB), it needed to be split into smaller datasets, so we tried this method. PS: It works without the loop if run for one table at a time. But its quite a manual effort.

[image]

Thanks,
Piyush

Answer (score 0):

To answer the issue of the error message.  If you are going to pass a variable in to a query using the bigquery magics command you need to use the [params](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/magics.html) flag.
Your code should end up looking something like this:

```
t="table_name"
my_params = {"t": t}

%%bigquery --params $my_params
select @t
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider and try below approach.

Instead of using *BigQuery magics*, you may use [BiQuery Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#download_query_results_using_the_client_library) for Python. From there, you may loop to your list of tables by using **f string** as shown on below sample code.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

bqclient = bigquery.Client()

scoring_tables = ["`your-project-id.your-dataset.test_table1`",
"`your-project-id.your-dataset.test_table2`","`your-project-id.your-dataset.test_table3`"]

for t in scoring_tables:
    # Download query results.
    query_string = f"""
    SELECT * FROM {t}
    """

    property_data_score_00 = (
        bqclient.query(query_string)
        .result()
        .to_dataframe(
            # Optionally, explicitly request to use the BigQuery Storage API. As of
            # google-cloud-bigquery version 1.26.0 and above, the BigQuery Storage
            # API is used by default.
            create_bqstorage_client=True,
        )
    )
    score_data = property_data_score_00.copy()
    score_data.set_index('HH_ID',inplace = True)
    print(score_data)
```

Sample output of above code:
[image]